# SSAS 2005 processing measure group time out

Tags: ssas

I have this measure group taking too long to process then time out. The measure group is based on a view, which is rather complicated with many table joins, union, left outer join etc on a OLTP database. Is this the reason the processing taking so long? What's the options? I am thinking either to materialized the view to a data warehouse or using multiple partitions (query binding on the view) so each query/partition will be much smaller? I haven't tried both but would like to hear from your opinions.

--update

The error information:

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the 'Vw Fact Stock By Day' partition of the 'Stocks' measure group for the 'xxx' cube from the xxx database.
```

Comment: Which component times out? If it is Analysis Services timing out as it does not get at least the first record within some time of issuing the select statement, I would not think partitioning would help, as, presumably, the database engine would need a similar amount of time to deliver the first record. I would go the route to optimize the relational part, either optimizing the view definition, or - as you proposed - materializing the view.

Comment: @FrankPl I have added error info. I think this is a time out from the relational database?

Comment: If you just need to get across this timeout to get things working, and are not interested in performance tuning  at the moment, you can go to the data source of your AS project, click on "Edit", and select "All" in the left. Then you can configure a "Connect Timeout" and a "General Timeout". I think setting these to `0` means `infinite`, i. e. no timeout.

Comment: @FrankPl I probably need to tune the performance of the view/query anyway because it's really taking too much time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case partitioning speeds up processing grately (cause parallel comutations are faster on servers) I have partitions for every day. (They are generated via C#)

But for perfomance profit you should have

1) Slice on every partition! Not only query binding

2) Using partitions you'll probably get rid of timeout, but it still may take a long time, so materialized and indexed view is a next step, if needed.